# Saving xlsx file in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, xlsx, axlsx

I've been trying to generate an XLSX file in my app. I'm using the gem 'acts_as_xlsx'.

The problem is that the document is generated in the background, and I don't want to render a view. It's a script that should return the XLSX file.

I'm trying to do something like:

`file = File.open("report.xlsx", relation.to_xlsx, type: "application/vnd.openxmlformates-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet")`

This returns an error as the second argument of the File.open must be a string.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`to_xlsx` should return the Axlsx package. The package will save itself to a file:

```
relation.to_xlsx.serialize("report.xlsx")
```

However, if you are emailing it, all you need is to place that as the attachment. You don't need to save it as a file:

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  def export(users)
    content = User.to_xlsx(data: users).to_stream.string
    attachments["Users.xlsx"] = {mime_type: Mime::XLSX, content: content}
    ...
  end
end
```

Also, you'll notice above, `acts_as_xlsx` registers `Mime::XLSX` for you. So you can use that instead of the long mime string.

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't using any controller or mailer, I was generating a file in a script.
It helped. Thanks. Finally my code was:
    relation_xlsx = relation.to_xlsx;
    relation_xlsx.serialize("report.xlsx");
    serialized_relation = relation_xlsx.to_stream;

    file = File.open('report_streamed.xlsx', 'w');
    file.write(serialized_relation.read)

It is necessary to separate the methods .to_xlsx and .serialize because serialize returns true, so if afterwards you try: relation_xlsx.to_stream it will return "Undefined method to_stream for true:TrueClass